# How to remove unwanted bold text after \bf{}?

Tags: bold

I have used the following script-

```
Let's consider That you are constructing \bf{rational numbers}for the first time using natural numbers and so we don't have any idea about the \bf{division operator}
```

And the ouput produced is -

Let’s consider That you are constructing **rational numbers for the first time using natural numbers and so we don’t have any idea about the divi
sion operator** .

But I want only want the characters in between \bf{} to have bold font.
How to do it ??

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't use `\bf`, which has been deprecated for about 25 years. `\textbf{rational numbers}` is the right syntax.

Comment: How many times are those questions asked and even answered? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, it form uncountable set ;-)

Answer (score 5):

`\bf` should never be used, it has been deprecated about 25 years ago.

Anyway, its syntax was like `{\bf rational numbers}`, but ***don't*** do this.

The correct syntax is

```
\textbf{rational numbers}
```

Compare closely the three lines (the first shows the issue, due to `\bf` being a declaration that goes on until the scope in which it appears ends). The second and third lines differ slightly, but significantly (and the last line is the correct one).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % for scoping the issue
Some \bf{big stuff} here
\endgroup

Some {\bf big stuff} here

Some \textbf{big stuff} here

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same can be seen, perhaps better, with `\it` and `\textit` (same as for `\bf` and `\textbf`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % for scoping the issue
Some \it{big stuff} here
\endgroup

Some {\it big stuff} here

Some \textit{big stuff} here

\end{document}
```

[image]